# relative paths to stylesheets not working in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm having some trouble getting my stylesheets to work.  I'm still using `Angular2` and the seed I downloaded is newer than the one I worked with before so at that point using `moduleId : module.id` had been deprecated.  Without the `moduleId` relative paths aren't working and I now have to do the full path starting from the `app` folder.  Is this just the way I have to do things or is there a fix for this?

I've come across a few articles, one suggesting we use `moduleId: module.id + ""` to fix the problem because webpack uses numbers while Angular expects a string.  I still got an error telling me the `css` file failed to load when attempting to use relative paths.

I tried updating my `webpack` and `angular-animations` which went successfully but didn't change the behavior.  I wish I could find a link back to the seed so I can show exactly which one I'm using, but here's the `package.json` file, hopefully this sheds some light on things.

```
{
  "name": "angular2-seed",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple starter Angular2 project",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress",
    "watch": "npm run build -- --watch",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 3000 --content-base src",
    "start": "npm run server"
  },
  "contributors": [
    "Rob Wormald <robwormald@gmail.com>",
    "PatrickJS <github@gdi2290.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Angular2",
    "angular2-seed",
    "official angular 2 seed",
    "official angular2 seed"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed#readme"
}
```

Ok I just realize the link is in the package file so I guess you guys can have a look at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to upgrade. I suggest you install Angular CLI create a new project with `ng new MyNewAwesomeAngularProject` and move your code over, fix the stuff that comes up. In the long run this will save you from some big headaches.

https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: only thing about this, is I'm stuck with Windows Vista for right now and I can't get anything higher than node 5.7 installed.